# Can verbal statements and advertising literature be considered in addition to a written contract during dispute?

Tags: contract-law, united-kingdom, breach-of-contract, scotland

I was wondering if there is precedent for aspects such as advertising literature and verbal statements being considered in a contract dispute, even if not included in writing?

To give a specific example, when applying to universities, brochures, open days, reputation, advertising videos etc are all used to encourage students to go - and they give a sense of what is to be expected. However, the contracts students agree to do not usually include any of these things.

In a dispute over services provided, can these other aspects be used in addition to the contract, and if so, is there any legal precedent?